# How to send username from React Native app to Dialogflow for bot to use in responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot app using react native and dialogflow. I have the general chatbot working (code below). My next step is that I want to store the user's name (using react native) on their device (this I know how to do) and also send this name to dialogflow so that the bot can respond with the user's name (No idea how to do this last step). I have done a lot of research on how to accomplish this, and perhaps I am just too new to dialogflow, but I have failed to figure out how to do this. From what I have gathered, I believe I will need to set an entity from my react.js files, which then can be accessed as a parameter in dialogflow. I see that the react native module dialogflow has a setEntity method, but with dialogflow_V2, this has been moved from /setEntity to sessions.setEntityType. I am totally confused on how I would implement this in dialogflow_V2 (and how "/" differs from "sessions."). I noticed that when I send a query request, there is a java object returned that has a session key. Do I need to somehow use this session key to use setEntityType, and if so, would this not only be applied on particular queries? Any clarification or guidance would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

The main screen for my chatbot is provided as code below (note it uses the new functional component style, not yet as commonly seen as using classes). To run this, one would have to connect this screen to the app.js file using react-navigation, and create a env.js file (sensitive information), that can be accessed from dialogflow. A nice tutorial for how to do this using classes is in this link: https://blog.jscrambler.com/build-a-chatbot-with-dialogflow-and-react-native/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { Dialogflow_V2 } from 'react-native-dialogflow-text'; //correct module for using expo
import {dialogflowconfig} from './env';

const TalkScreen = props => {
  const BOT_USER = {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'FAQ Bot',
    avatar: 'https://i.imgur.com/7k12EPD.png'
  }

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(
    [
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: `Hi! I am the FAQ bot  from Jscrambler.\n\nHow may I help you with today?`,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: BOT_USER
      }
    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
      dialogflowconfig.client_email,
      dialogflowconfig.private_key,
      Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US,
      dialogflowconfig.project_id
    )
  })

  const sendBotResponse = (text, message) => {
    let msg = {
      _id: messages.length + 1,
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: BOT_USER
    };
    let newMessage = GiftedChat.append(messages, message);
    setMessages(GiftedChat.append(newMessage, [msg]));
  }

  const handleGoogleResponse = (result, message) => {
    //let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0];
    let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentText;
    sendBotResponse(text, message);
  }

  const onSend = (message) => {
      setMessages(GiftedChat.append(messages, message));
      let mesg = message[0].text;
      Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
        mesg,
        result => handleGoogleResponse(result,message),
        error => console.log(error)
      )
  }

  // Not currently used in code, but anticipated for sending username to dialogflow
  const entities = [{
    "name":"username",
    //"extend":true,
    //"entries":[
    //    {
    //        "value":"Media Markt",
    //        "synonyms":["Media Markt"]
    //    }
    //]
   }];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color: '#aaa', textAlign: 'center' }}>
             Let's catch up!
        </Text>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id: 1
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export const screenOptions = {
    headerTitle: "My Best Friend",
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffedff',
        shadowColor: 'transparent',
    },
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default TalkScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities are probably not what you want. These are types that are used to determine possible values for parameters in matched Intents.

Instead, you can pass additional values that the fulfillment webhook might use as a [Context parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialogflow-text#contexts).

So your code might look something like

```
const contexts = [{
  name: "userinfo",
  lifespan: 1,
  parameters: {
      "name": username
  }
}];
Dialogflow_V2.setContexts(contexts);

Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
  mesg,
  result => handleGoogleResponse(result,message),
  error => console.log(error)
)
```

The documentation also talks about a "permanent context", but isn't clear about where this needs to be set.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, I now have the username functionality in my react native app working with dialogflow from using the solution you provided. Just a note for anyone else who may want to use this solution. To access this parameter in the response of a given intent, use #userinfo.name. Thank you so much PRISONER! You rock!